# How to create raster stack from names on R

Tags: raster, r, stack

I have a dataframe containing the best predictors by their contribution to a model:

```r
bestpredictors
           var contrib
2  Pfallwinter  8.1141
15      Tofall 58.0000
23          ai  5.3573
26     radmean  7.9753
27   radseason  0.9027
```

Every variable name is also a raster object. So, how can I make a raster stack with those variables? Like this:

```r
predictors<-stack(Pfallwinter,Tofall,ai,radmean,radseason)
```

I have tried to extracting the string character and using the `do.call` and `eval` functions but seems that isn't the correct way, because they can't call the object already saved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `mget()` to search for objects given a character vector.

```r
predictors<-stack(mget(unique(as.character(bestpredictors$var))))
```